# How to change delete confirmation message title kendo jQuery grid?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to get remove title from the Kendo MVC jquery Grid Destroy Command confirmation message ? Please see the screenshot.
below my grid command. I want to remove "locahost:50144 says" title.

```
command: [{ className: "btn ez-icon-btn text-danger", name: "destroy", text: "" }]
```

[image]

Can anyone help me how to do that?

FYI, I'm working on ASP.NET MVC with Kendo jQuery Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mobile edit confirmation box.
hiding the title is not possible ([Kendo response](https://www.telerik.com/forums/dialog-change-kendo-confirm-title))

**Snippet:**

```js
var dataOne = [{
    Firstname: 'Tom',
    Lastname: 'Dillens'
  },
  {
    Firstname: 'John',
    Lastname: 'Wicked'
  },
  {
    Firstname: 'Jane',
    Lastname: 'Candy'
  }
];

$('#one').kendoGrid({
  dataSource: dataOne,
  columns: [{
    field: 'Firstname'
  }, {
    field: 'Lastname'
  }, {
    command: 'destroy'
  }],
  mobile: "phone", // Use mobile confirmation alert
  editable: {
    confirmation: true,
    confirmDelete: "Yes"
  } // Required for mobile confirmation alert.
});
```

```css
.k-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10001;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: .5;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.k-window {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: #d5d5d5;
  color: #2e2e2e;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10001;
}

.k-dialog {
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 90px;
  min-height: 3em;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.k-button {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin: 5px;
}

.k-button:hover {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ededed;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<table id='one'></table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need to show confirmation message but need to hide title. How to hide title ?

Comment: Thank you Crezzur, If i use this <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> css then Alert message is coming without title means purpose served but my existing page css is broken. Could you give me just exactly css for "Use mobile confirmation alert" that I can use in this page. Thanks !

Comment: or simply how can catch title portion to hide. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what your issue is now, the mobile confirmation does not show a title, or am i wrong?

Comment: I don't want show title , the mobile confirmation(your solution) is working fine. but I can't add whole css file because its broken my existing page. I just need "mobile confirmation" css only. Thanks

Comment: I have added the basic css to the snippet, this way you can edit a bit the way you want